# What are the challenges or problems in Backing up and restoring Open source softwares like openstack and kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, backup, open-source, openstack, restore

I would like to understand the existing problems in the field of openstack and kubernetes with respect to backup and restore. Any link or reference to any research related matter would also be helpful.

Comment: Be forewarned that SO [generally disapproves](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) of these open-ended questions

Answer (score 0):

*my USD$0.02:* There are [several projects](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Akubernetes+backup&ref=opensearch) that I know of which attempt to backup k8s clusters at the metadata level

We focus on etcd backups, since our risk is wider than just the k8s descriptors, but as the adage goes: "they're not backups until you've tested them," which I (unfortunately) have not made the time to try

One also needs to exercise caution because any cluster state backups will contain cleartext `Secret` descriptors; so any backup solution needs to be aware of encryption or to skip over those descriptors